Unable to pass column names in IoT rules for timestream table
I am trying to create an IoT rule for inserting the data in the AWS Timestream table and I configured my query as below:
SELECT ax-lt-011 AS first_column, ax-lt-021 AS second_column FROM "iot/topic"  

but it gives the below error:

I also tried this query:
SELECT ax-lt-011, ax-lt-021 FROM "iot/topic"

But it also gives the same error. So, is it because of my column names having "-" in between? I can't change the source data.
I can load the data using * but I wanted to load the data as per relational tables, therefore, went ahead with aliases.

I'm not familiar with AWS but as this seems to be a SQL error, try using [ ] around your column names.
SELECT [ax-lt-011] AS first_column ...


It gives me this error Expected a ']' or ',' but got INT(-11). Array literals should follow the format [expression1, expression2] ax-lt-011] AS first_column FROM "iot/topic" --------^ at 1:9

This could be due to the what SQL database you are using, SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL etc. Try using backticks ` instead of [ ].  Can you confirm which SQL database you are using.

Backticks don't work. I have mentioned that I am using AWS timestream as a time series database.

My only other suggestion is use double quotation marks, similar to the from clause "iot/topic". I'm not familiar with AWS, but it looks to be a case of finding the correct syntax to deal with delimited identifiers

It treats it as a string value
